# Вызов ajax в модальном окне, вызванном при помощи ajax

Tags: jquery

Доброй ночи. Возникла проблема, состоящая в том, что ajax-запрос не отправляет данные к php файлу. Я долго размышлял, в чём же может быть дело и, похоже, додумался. Дело в том, что содержимое модального окна в моём случае загружается при помощи ajax-запроса. А сам контент модалки - форма с полями, которая так же отправляет ajax-запрос к php-файлу. Но, почему-то данные к php-файлу не поступают. И почему-то мне кажется, что всё дело в том, что данные отправляются из ajax-загруженного модального окна и почему-то мне кажется, что так нельзя. Конкретного материала по такой теме я не нашёл, по этому решил спросить. Вполне возможно, что я допустил ошибку в своём коде. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в проблеме. Данные к php файлу отправляются таким образом:

```
$('#krok-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'receipt/krok-receipt.php',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Data was sent successfuly');
            $('#blank-frame').html(data);
            $('#blank-frame').css({'padding' : '15px'});

            $('.must-hide').hide('slow', function(){
                $(this).detach();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Сам вызов модального окна выглядит вот так, где **js/jquery.data-form-request.js** - скрипт, описанный выше.

```
$('#krok-modal').click(function() {
        $.arcticmodal({
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'modals/krok.php',
            ajax: {
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: console.log('AJAX-loaded modal launched'),
            },
            afterOpen: function(data, el) {
                $.getScript('js/jquery.input.js');
                $.getScript('js/jquery.data-form-request.js');
            }
        });
    });
```

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй через $(document).on('click'...

```
$(document).on('click', '#krok-modal', function() {
        $.arcticmodal({
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'modals/krok.php',
            ajax: {
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: console.log('AJAX-loaded modal launched'),
            },
            afterOpen: function(data, el) {
                $.getScript('js/jquery.input.js');
                $.getScript('js/jquery.data-form-request.js');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: А что должно было измениться? Всё по-прежнему, данные не отправляются.

Comment: Через on срабатывает делегирование событий, даже если элемент на странице появится после загрузки скрипта - он будет обрабатыватся.